# X11 Forwarding: GUI appears in the remote server instead of client

Tags: ssh, x11

I have two machines, **PC1** and **PC2**. in **PC1** I have [Msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) and Xming installed on Windows 7  while in the second machine **PC2** I have Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), Xming is also installed. I configured both machines to use ssh and the necessary configurations for X11 forwarding in `(/etc/ssh/sshd_config)`. in **PC1** I have also to set DISPLAY variable:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
```

I want to ssh from PC1 to PC2 but I have one problem:
The following command works fine:

```
ssh -Y username@PC2 gedit
```

it shows gedit on PC1 as expected.
But when I ssh to PC2 then I start gedit:

```
$ ssh -Y username@PC2  # Now I am logged in to PC2
$ gedit
```

The GUI appears in **PC2** instead of **PC1**

Could you please explain what's going wrong with the second way?

Comment: What is `$DISPLAY` set to on PC2?

Comment: You pretty much never need to set `DISPLAY` manually. And if you have a configuration file which replaces a correct `DISPLAY` variable with an incorrect one you have set manually, it can cause things to break.

Comment: @Ignacio In PC2 (ubuntu 18.04 on wsl with xming, DISPLAY=:0)

Comment: @kasperd : the DISPLAY variable sometimes must be set in my case if it is not set the GUI doesn't appear

Comment: And that's why it displays on PC2. You need to let sshd set `$DISPLAY` appropriately.

Comment: @Ignacio: in PC2 when I installed Xming I added `export DISPLAY=:0` in `~/.bashrc` to be able to use Xming

Comment: That's nice and all, but it's interfering with showing the GUI on PC1.

Comment: @Navaro That line is your problem. You shouldn't have put it there in the first place.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams & @kasperd: Thank you very much, I solved that by removing `export DISPLAY=:0` from PC2 `.bashrc`. In PC1, before connecting, I have to `export DISPLAY=localhost:0`. That solves the problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Can you please write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X forwarding over SSH is dependent on sshd setting the value of `$DISPLAY` appropriately, so forcing an override on the remote system will interfere. If you *must* set it regardless then only set it if it doesn't already have a value:

```
: ${DISPLAY:=:0}
```